# Method to compute a logarithmic value within a specific range

Tags: logarithms

Hello I'm trying to create a formula that returns the y from the graph image below.
It's always within a range. For example (0.5 - 2) for any x value.

The closest I've been to is:
1 /(1/log2 (x) ) ^ 2 + 0.5 (min range value)

Whose graph looks like this:
[image]

But I need something like this:
[image]

Comment: $$f(x)=\dfrac{5\cos x-3}5$$

Comment: If you can do without the logarithms, that hand-drawn curve looks logistic. Try playing around with $\dfrac a{b+e^{cx}} + d$. For instance, $\dfrac{1.5}{1+ e^{2x}} + 0.5$

Comment: Another option is a hill type function $-x / (k + x)$

Comment: I didn't know about logistic curves, looks very similar to what I need